# Why isn't the ProxyJump parameter inherited for specified IP range in SSH config?

Tags: ssh

I use a jump server (lab1) to connect to servers with IPs starting with 10.*. All other servers shouldn't use lab1 as jump server and need a different key.

In the main config there are two included configs and some general settings:

**Main ssh config:**

```
Include ~/.ssh/lab.conf
Include ~/.ssh/prod.conf

Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  User rg2531
  ForwardAgent yes
  ServerAliveInterval 30
  ServerAliveCountMax 10
  IdentityFile /SSH_keys/prod/id_rsa
```

**lab.conf:**

```
Host 10.*
  ProxyJump lab1

# Jump server
Host lab1
  HostName 134.121.15.2
  IdentityFile /SSH_keys/dev/id_rsa

# Individual hosts
Host lab2
  HostName 10.10.10.2
```

**prod.conf:**

```
Host prod1
  HostName 122.140.12.1
```

When I connect to lab2, it should use ProxyJump to connect me through jump server (lab1), because I have a rule for `Host 10.*`
But it's not behave as expected.

It works only if I put `ProxyJump lab1` into `Host lab2` section:

```
Host lab2
  HostName 10.10.10.2
  ProxyJump lab1
```

Why `ProxyJump` param is not inherited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it works of the name that you are using. If you used `ssh 10.10.10.2` your client would use the ProxyJump setting from your configuration.  But if you  `ssh lab2`, the `lab2` value doesn't match `10.*` so the setting isn't used. So it isn't about inheritance, it is that the ssh doesn't re-evaluate the configuration once the configuration for `lab2 is loaded and it finds the Hostname value.

If all your computers on that `10.10.10.*` network happen to be named lab*, you could do something like this.

```
Host lab1
  HostName 134.121.15.2
  IdentityFile /SSH_keys/dev/id_rsa

Host lab* !lab1
  ProxyJump lab1
```